# How to paginate categories in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am  creating a blog using Laravel, it is working fine except that I want to display posts of a specific category on a certain page but I want to paginate them to display 3 posts per page, but I cant figure out how to use paginate method on the posts of that specific category, please assist?

```
//Testing the Blog
    public function getBlog(){

        //Get all Laravel Posts(Have category of 1 ) in categories table
        $laravel = Category::find(1)->posts()->whereNotNull("title")->whereNotNull("imageName")->whereNotNull("slug")->whereNotNull("created_at")->get();

        return view('blog.index')->withLaravels($laravel);
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried with laravel paginate eloquent queries like, **$laravel = Category::find(1)->posts()->whereNotNull("title")->whereNotNull("imageName")->whereNotNull("slug")->whereNotNull("created_at")->paginate(3);**

Comment: Thanks I have tested it and it works